# Rails 3.1: Intermittent 500 Internal Server Error when serving uncompressed assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading an app to Rails 3.1. Quote often, Firebug will complain about some assets. Here are some errors pasted from Firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://unstilted.dev/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"
jquery...?body=1
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://unstilted.dev/assets/admin/pages/file_attachments.js"
file_a...ents.js
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://unstilted.dev/assets/admin/file_attachments/sortable.js?body=1"
sortab...?body=1
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://unstilted.dev/assets/jquery.js?body=1"
```

Refreshing the page would yield different assets showing the same error. When I copy and paste the URL I see the files just fine.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 11.04
- Apache+Passenger 3.0.9

**How do I fix this?**

**UPDATE**: Log file

In this particular instance, `jquery-ui.js` was showing an error in Firebug.  My log file looked like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 06 22:24:39 +0800 2011
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 06 22:24:39 +0800 2011


Started GET "/admin/site/sites/storage.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 06 22:24:39 +0800 2011
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 06 22:24:39 +0800 2011
  Processing by Admin::Site::SitesController#storage as JS
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)
  ...
Rendered admin/site/sites/storage.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 21.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/admin/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 06 22:24:39 +0800 2011
Served asset /admin/logo.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

It seems to have skipped `jquery-ui.js`!

**UPDATE** Oct 1, 2011:

I tried it out with the standalone passenger (`passenger start`) as it seems to give a more descriptive error. This is what happens when I try to load just the `jquery.js` file and press `CTRL-R` repeatedly to refresh my browser and load that asset repeatedly.

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-01 21:40:18 +0800
[ pid=29485 thr=3066030960 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:931 time=2011-10-01 21:40:18.691 ]: Uncaught exception in PassengerServer client thread:
   exception: Cannot read response from backend process: Connection reset by peer (104)
   backtrace:
     in 'void Client::forwardResponse(Passenger::SessionPtr&, Passenger::FileDescriptor&, const Passenger::AnalyticsLogPtr&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:603)
     in 'void Client::handleRequest(Passenger::FileDescriptor&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:857)
     in 'void Client::threadMain()' (HelperAgent.cpp:950)

2011/10/01 21:40:18 [error] 29522#0: *16 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /assets/jquery.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "get.unstilted.dev:3000"
[ pid=29674 thr=78131090 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-10-01 21:40:18.699 ]: *** Exception PGError in application (server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
) (process 29674, thread #<Thread:0x9505f24>):
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:276:in `exec'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:276:in `block in clear_cache!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in `each_value'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in `clear_cache!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:303:in `disconnect!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in disconnect!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in `each'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in `disconnect!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:35:in `block in disconnect_with_synchronization!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:34:in `disconnect_with_synchronization!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in `block in clear_all_connections!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in `each_value'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in `clear_all_connections!'
        from /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@unstilted/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `clear_all_connections!'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:398:in `before_handling_requests'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:204:in `start_request_handler'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /home/ramon/.passenger/standalone/3.0.9-x86-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.2-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
cache: [GET /assets/jquery.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
[ pid=29485 thr=3064224624 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:921 time=2011-10-01 21:40:18.734 ]: Couldn't forward the HTTP response back to the HTTP client: It seems the user clicked on the 'Stop' button in his browser.
```

Comment: What does your application logfile say about the error?

Comment: @netmute, I added the answer to your question up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the middle of Passenger and Rails 3.1 PostgreSQL adapter.
According to this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1339
Rails 3.1.1.rc1 should have this issue fixed.

Also stop using `PassengerSpawnMethod conservative` because it makes Passenger & eventually REE performance optimizations useless - it spawns separate Rails instances - no sharing of common code.

Comment: Thanks! I've upgraded to 3.1.1.rc2!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me I think it was some cached assets or something.

I ran

```
rake assets:clean
```

and then requested the page again. This generated real error messages I could use to debug.

It turned out that one of my JS files still had the old require syntax with <>s.

Hope this solves your problem too, I know it was frustrating!

Comment: Actually maybe it was a fluke. The exact same site works with rails server, but not in Passenger. There are errors in the apache error log about a the response not being valid.

Comment: You're right - passenger seems to have caused the errors! Add that to your answer? :) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is to tell passenger to use the 'conservative' spawn method.

in your apache2.conf

```
PassengerSpawnMethod conservative
```

Comment: Thanks. While this answer will solve the problem, the one of gertas explains why. :)